# Nested JSON show wrong values PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to create a JSON format from 3 mysql tables using PHP. Below is my table:
[image]

To create a JSON format from these 3 tables I am using this code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "mydb";

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $database) or die ("Unable to connect"); 


$sql = "SELECT model_id FROM 1Model";

$sqlRun = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
$json = array();
$role_model = mysqli_num_rows($sqlRun);

if($role_model > 0){
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlRun)){
        $row_array= array();
        $model_id = $row['model_id'];
        $json[$i]['model_id'] = $row['model_id'];     

        $role_qry = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id_cat, cat_name, model_id FROM 1Category WHERE model_id= $model_id");
        while($role_fet = mysqli_fetch_array($role_qry)){
            $json[$i]['id_cat']['id_cat'] = $role_fet['id_cat'];
            $json[$i]['cat_name']['cat_name'] = $role_fet['cat_name'];


            $cat_array = array();
            $cat_pk = $role_fet['id_cat'];
            $test_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id_item, item_name, id_cat FROM 1Item WHERE id_cat = $cat_pk");
            $j = 0;
            while($test_fet = mysqli_fetch_array($test_query)){
                $json[$i]['item_list']['items'][$j] = array('item_name' => $test_fet['item_name']);
                $j++;
            }
        }
        $i++;

    }
}
    header('Content-type: text/javascript');
    echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

My expected result is json object will filter based on the model name and category name, something like below:

```
[
{
    "model_id": "1",
    "cat_name": {
        "cat_name": "Box Medium"

        "item_list": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_name": "Box Medium Orange"
                },
                {
                    "item_name": "Box Medium Purple"
                },
                {
                    "item_name": "Box Medium White"
                },
                {
                    "item_name": "Box Medium Grey"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
},
{
    "model_id": "2",
    "id_cat": {
        "id_cat": "6"
    },
    "cat_name": {
        "cat_name": "Square Large"
    }
},
{
    "model_id": "3"
}
```

]

But I don't know why my result children values not filtered based on parent id. 
Right now the code encode json as result below:

```
[
    {
        "model_id": "1",
        "id_cat": {
            "id_cat": "3"
        },
        "cat_name": {
            "cat_name": "Box Large"
        },
        "item_list": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_name": "Box Medium Orange"
                },
                {
                    "item_name": "Box Medium Purple"
                },
                {
                    "item_name": "Box Medium White"
                },
                {
                    "item_name": "Box Medium Grey"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "model_id": "2",
        "id_cat": {
            "id_cat": "6"
        },
        "cat_name": {
            "cat_name": "Square Large"
        }
    },
    {
        "model_id": "3"
    }
]
```

Anyone can help me on this, tried to find on the web but unlucky. What I am trying to do is to get a json format hierarchical, **model=parent**, **category=subparent**, **item=child**. Thanks for any helps

Comment: Isn't the JSON you have now the same as your desired JSON?

Comment: Hi, no is not the category name is wrong. It should be medium category :(

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) instead.

Comment: Thanks for remind me the security issue, will do this at the end